# How do I show a sequence is bounded, use for one part of the monotone convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So the monotone convergence theorem states that if a sequence is bounded and monotone then it converges.

Now I am trying to prove that the sequence defined recursively as $x_1 = \sqrt 2$, $x_{n+1}=\sqrt {2x_n}$ converges and to find it's limit.

I am able to show that the sequence is monotone by determining if the ratio of $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is greater than and equal to or less than or equal to 1.  I am even know what the limit is.

My dilemma is I am not sure how to determine if this sequence is bounded and I am not quite sure what I need to do to show that its bounded.  Can anyone offer a few hints or strategies?  I know that it is bounded below by $\sqrt2$; however the sequence is increasing so I need to show that there is an upperbound as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  Use Induction. Suppose $x_n < 2$, what can you say about $x_{n+1}$?

Comment: I get it, but one question how did you choose $x_n < 2$?  Common sense or some other method?

Comment: Maybe you could use the derivative of $f(x)= (2x)^{1/2}$; show it is positive, and use the fact that $x_1>2$.

Comment: I solved $x=\sqrt{2x}$ to get $2$. Any number larger than the limit of the sequence would also work, essentially I skipped to finding the limit.

Comment: @user99680 $x_1 <2$ and I am not sure if derivatives are useful here.